# Erro ao tentar acessar informações do Banco de Dados

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7, conexão

Estou migrando aplicação que foi desenvolvida no Delphi 7, que antes utilizava o banco de dados Firebird, dai agora estou fazendo a aplicação se comunicar com o banco PostgreSQL. Consegui, após arrumar alguns erros no código, realizar a comunicação corretamente com o banco, porém quando vou realizar determinadas atividades na aplicação o seguinte erro aparece quando tento acessar informações do banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Revisei os ClientDataSet's para verificar se o *Active* estava em **False** e não encontrei nenhum erro neles, se tiverem alguma ideia

Ao debugar o programa o seguinte erro ocorreu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que acredito ser a mesma coisa que ocorre no primeiro erro, dai quando tento continuar ele me aponta a seguinte linha em destaque:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem, erros de acesso de memória geralmente acontecem quando se tenta acessar um objeto que já foi destruído. Tente debugar o programa para ver qual o problema. Sem mais informações não temos como ajudar.

Comment: @Genos Editei a pergunta com o que ocorre quando debugo o a aplicação

Comment: Esse dataset que você está tentando abrir na imagem existe (quero dizer, foi criado e ainda não foi destruído)?

Comment: É que na verdade esse código fonte não é meu, estou tentando apenas conectar a aplicação ao PostgreSQL, no postgre eu já recriei todas as tabelas com todas as informações que tinha no Firebird, e não mexi em nada no código, por tentar alterar o Banco ele poderia ter alterado isso, pois no Firebird a aplicação funciona normalmente

Comment: @Genos E como eu poderia verificar se esse dataset foi criado e não foi destruido

Comment: Durante o debug, um passo antes de entrar na função Open (indicada na sua imagem), verifique o valor do dataset. Se a instância estiver inválida o  delphi provavelmente vai te indicar com uma mensagem semelhante a do erro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47937/discussion-between-genos-and-r-santos).

Comment: @Genos Isso não teria a ver com meu arquivo .DFM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do access violation na realidade é o componente RxLib - Delphi 7 que precisava ser instalado. O erro do Rave Reports deve estar conectado com isso!